# How does constructor inheritance work in C++?

Tags: c++

According to my research, C++ does not automatically inherit constructors in subclasses, so given the code below:

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
    
    foo(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
    foo() : a(0), b(0) {}
};

struct bar : foo{};

struct baz
{
    int a;
    
    baz(int a) : a(a) {}
    baz() : a(0) {}
};

struct qux : baz{};
```

We should not be able to create an object baz in the same way as foo without first redefining the constructor.

```
int main(){
    
    bar b(1,2);
    
    std::cout << b.a;
}
```

gives an error as we should expect. However

```
int main(){
    
    qux b(1);
    
    std::cout << b.a;
}
```

returns 1, despite qux having no explicit constructor. Did it receive its constructor from baz or is this a quirk of it being a single parameter constructor, or is it something else?

Also, if I do go in and add the constructor to bar

```
bar(int a, int b)  
{
   this->a = a;
   this->b = b;
}
```

and

`bar(int a, int b) : foo(a,b) {}` work, but `bar(int a, int b) : a(a), b(a) {}` does not. Why is this?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Well, [doesn't work for me](https://godbolt.org/z/eE9fje).

Comment: it works with "-std=c++2a" flag

Comment: [Here](https://wandbox.org/) is the online compiler I was using. Go ahead and paste it there if you are interested.

Answer (score 3):

```
qux b(1);
```

works because implicit conversion takes place (from int to baz)
and then move constructor is used to create qux from baz

delete move constructor or make baz(int) constructor explicit and it will not work

```
struct baz
{
    int a;
    
    baz(const baz& o) = delete;
    /*explicit*/ baz(int a) : a(a) {}
    baz() : a(0) {}
};
```

as for

> but bar(int a, int b) : a(a), b(a) {} does not.

it will work if you create foo and pass it to move constructor like this:

```
 bar b({1,2});
```

Comment: Making the constructor explicit avoids the implicit conversion.